# Azure RunAs Account certificate expiration warning

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

For a customer i use a stop/start script for azure vm. A while ago the certificate for the RunAs account expired, so the scheduled start of the system did not happen one day. Is there a way to get a warning for the expiration of the certificate used for the Azure RunAs Account?

Comment: I think it is not one issue about Azure AD B2C.

Comment: You might be right, but azure support asked me to add an item with this tag and send them the link...